# Send this instance as callback parameter

Tags: c++, callback, this-pointer

I have simple UI class and I need to send UI element instance to callbacks for each element, so I can (much like in javascript) manipulate element which called the callback.
This requires to send instance of `this` to the function registered as callback. How do I do that?
Current state:

```
class Opencv_Button {
private:
    bool (*callback)(void*);                 //Callback WITHOUT the current button isntance
    //bool(*callback)(Opencv_Button, void*); //this is CALLBACK I WANT instead
    void* callback_param;                    //parameter set by user
    bool state;
    bool mouse(int, int, int);
public:
    Opencv_Button(int, int, int, int);
    void setCallback(bool(*)(void*), void*);
    //void setCallback(bool(*)(Opencv_Button, void*), void*);  //This is what I WANT TO USE
    void draw(Mat*, bool);
    void val(const char*);
    char value[30];
};
```

Now, there is the function that calls the callback:

```
bool Opencv_Button::mouse(int mx, int my, int button) 
{
    if(/*click conditions satisfied*/) 
        {
             /*CLICK!!!*/
                  if(callback!=0)
                     callback(callback_param);
                     /*Instead I WANT:*/
                     //callback(*this/*some THIS instance*/, callback_param);
                 return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

So, I can do something like this in callback:

```
bool buttonCallback(Opencv_Button*but, void*param) {
     but->val("I was clicked!!!");
}
```

Comment: What's the problem in doing that exactly?

Comment: Problem is that `&this` returns error, because the `this` is reference itself. And I don't see a way of dereverencing variables.

Comment: @TomášZato `this` is an `Opencv_Button*` - a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. The quick fix is to make sure your callback takes a pointer and you pass `this`:

```
bool (*callback)(Opencv_Button*, void*);
void setCallback(bool(*)(Opencv_Button*, void*), void*);
```

And call with:

```
callback(this, callback_param);
```

However, you'd likely be better off using references. You can have your function take a reference to `Opencv_Button`:

```
bool (*callback)(Opencv_Button&, void*);
void setCallback(bool(*)(Opencv_Button&, void*), void*);
```

Then call it with:

```
callback(*this, callback_param);
```

And your `buttonCallback` will look like this:

```
bool buttonCallback(Opencv_Button& but, void* param) {
  but.val("I was clicked!!!");
}
```

Comment: Shan't you use `.` to access class members in the last code example? Anyway, this is the answer. I decided to use `pointer` because I understand pointer mechanism better and references are confusing me. But thank you for posting both options!

Comment: @TomášZato Apologies, you're right. However, you're much better off using references. Raw pointers should only be used if necessary in C++.

Comment: If you insist on using references instead of pointers, is there some reason for this? I already said I'm not sure I know everything about references, so I'll sure read some interesting article about their advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Define the callback as

```
bool (*callback)(Opencv_Button*, void*);
```

and everythinng goes fine.